# Dagger dependency injection to service fails with "contactServiceModule must be set at DaggerAppComponent$Builder.build(DaggerAppComponent.java)"

Tags: java, android, service, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am using dagger for dependency injection, I apologize for not diving into deep and getting my hands on :)
I am using two modules(ApplicationModule, ContactServiceModule), with a component (AppComponent). I have initialized the Dagger in App.java, and I am trying to inject dependencies to a backgroud Service.
Here is the code snippet.
1)ApplicationModule.java

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private final App mApp;
    private Service contactService;

    public ApplicationModule(App app) {
        mApp = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ContactModel contactModel(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        return new ContactModel(mApp, database);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context appContext() {
        return mApp;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ContactController contactController() {
        return new ContactController(mApp.getAppComponent());
    }
    //.....Some more code
}
```

2)ContactServiceModule.java

```
    @Module
public class ContactServiceModule {

    ContactService contactService;

    public ContactServiceModule(ContactService contactService){
        this.contactService =contactService;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ContactService provideContactService() {
        return this.contactService;
    }
}
```

3)AppComponent.java

```
 @Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class,ContactServiceModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {


     ContactController contactController();

    Context appContext();
    //...Some code
    void inject(ContactController contactController);
    //...Some code
    void inject(ContactService contactService);
}
```

4)App.java

```
    public class App extends Application {
    private AppComponent mAppComponent;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlowManager.init(this);
        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return mAppComponent;
    }
}
```

5) ContactService.java

```
 public class ContactService extends Service {

    @Inject
    Context appContext;

    @Inject
    ContactController contactController;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }

    private AppComponent getAppComponent() {
       return  ((App)getApplication()).getAppComponent();
    }

}
```

It could be an issue of dependencies of UI threads injected into background services. But I do not understand how should I achieve the same dependencies to be injected into services. Or what should be the Ideal way to communicate between application level dependencies and services. I want the service to be running always in the background and listening to various intents and also communicate to other dependencies like eventbus etc.

Comment: I don't see you calling `new ContactServiceModule(service)` and adding it to the component anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

> contactServiceModule must be set at DaggerAppComponent$Builder.build(DaggerAppComponent.java)”

means that you have created a module with dependencies in the constructor (`ContactServiceModule` which has your `Service` as a parameter in the constructor). It follows that Dagger 2 cannot instantiate that module automatically and it must be instantiated in the builder when you create your component:

```
mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .contactServiceModule(contactService);
                .build();
```

However there is an underlying issue with the architecture you are trying to create. Services, like Activities, are designed to be autonomous and instantiated by the Android OS. Much in the same way you wouldn't directly pass as an Activity as a dependency to another Activity, you shouldn't make a Service a dependency. Instead you need to use `Intent`, service binding, or EventBus events to communicate with the service. The Android [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) documentation covers this and you should read it carefully before proceeding.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How can I inject EventBus instance into service. EventBus is a singleton dependency and I want the same to be injected into Service.